# iOS5 core data fetch freezes the app

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5, freeze

Starting from iOS5, my app started to freeze when using `fetchedResultsController`. I have attached the debugger result after quitting the simulator.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How many threads do you use? Where do you try to fetch?Paste the code. It seems that you have created a dead lock.

Comment: I am using master tableview and three other tableviews. when the list selection changes in master tableview i am using performselectorinbackground method to update three tableviews (basically i am making the fetchedresultscontroller nil and performing fetch again in those methods). The app freezes in the line  NSInteger totalCount = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] (inside fetchedresultscontroller block).App was working fine before iOS5.

Answer (score 4):

You say in the comments that you're using `performSelectorInBackground:` to update tableviews. This isn't right, all code affecting the UI should be executed on the main thread.

In addition (and I think this is what's causing the problem) you mustn't reuse a MOC across threads. Each thread must have its own MOC, which can then use the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

You should read [Apple's guide on this topic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1).